# Operação band com 64 bits

Tags: lua

Sei que no Lua 5.3 ([demonstração](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)) existem operadores de bit em 64 bits, como:

```
print(0xaaDbc4Cd17Af & 0xff00000000) --> DB 00 00 00 00
```

Existe algum algorítimo para realizar uma operação similiar à essa em outras versões? O Lua que executo vem com a biblioteca `bit32` respectivamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o nome diz, a biblioteca `bit32` não suporta 64 bits, somente 32 bits.

Se você precisa de 64 bits mesmo, vai ter que implementar a sua própria biblioteca usando por exemplo strings em vez de números.

Comment: Usar strings parece uma boa ideia no meu caso. Tem uma prévia de quantos bytes uma string com menos de 48 octetos ocuparia na memória?